# Remove this 'return' statement or make it conditional

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I'm using a code analysis software called SonarQube and it's giving me this error message saying that I should remove the return statement or make it conditional

I'm thinking about suppressing the message but not entirely sure yet.

```
protected static SubAccount GetSubAccountByProductCode(Holding acordHolding, string productCode, string optionType)
{
    var OptionTypeElement = ACORDUtil.CreateACORDElement("OptionType");
    const string subAccountPrefix = "SubAccount";
    var OlifeExtensions = new List<XmlElement>();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(optionType))
    {
        OptionTypeElement.InnerText = "V";
    }
    else
    {
        OptionTypeElement.InnerText = optionType;
    }
    OlifeExtensions.Add(OptionTypeElement);
    foreach (var acordSubAccount in acordHolding.Investment.SubAccount.Where(sa => sa.ProductCode.Equals(productCode)))
    {
        acordSubAccount.OLifEExtension.Add(ACORDUtil.CreateOLifEExtension(OlifeExtensions));
        return acordSubAccount;
    }

    //sub account not found, create one for this product symbol.
    var newSubAccount = new SubAccount();
    newSubAccount.id = string.Format("{0}-{1}", subAccountPrefix, productCode);
    newSubAccount.ProductCode = productCode;
    acordHolding.Investment.SubAccount.Add(newSubAccount);

    var oLifeExt = ACORDUtil.CreateOLifEExtension(OlifeExtensions);
    newSubAccount.OLifEExtension.Add(oLifeExt);
    return newSubAccount;
}
```

Make sonarqube not throw out an error message.

Comment: Your code contains two return statements. I assume it's complaining about the one in the `foreach` statement. It's not clear why you're using a `foreach` but returning in the first iteration - that's what's odd about the code, and I think Sonarqube is entirely within its rights to ask you to look at the code again.

Comment: Which line is it complaining about? You do have a return statement inside the `foreach` loop which is nasty though.

Comment: What do you think is the `foreach` loop doing? Now, what do you think is the `return` statement there within the `foreach` loop doing? Do you understand now? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Well, it'll only happen for one item, so you could *make it simpler and more obvious*:

```cs
var acordSubAccount = acordHolding.Investment.SubAccount.FirstOrDefault(
    sa => sa.ProductCode.Equals(productCode)); // possibly use == instead of .Equals?
if (acordSubAccount != null)
{
    acordSubAccount.OLifEExtension.Add(ACORDUtil.CreateOLifEExtension(OlifeExtensions));
    return acordSubAccount;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have a `return` in your `ForEach` loop.

It reads like you expect exactly one item to match, therefore perhaps change it to use `SingleOrDefault`. This will return exactly one element matching the condition, or throw an exception if there are multiple matching.

```
var acordSubAccount = acordHolding.Investment.SubAccount.SingleOrDefault(
    sa => sa.ProductCode.Equals(productCode));
if (acordSubAccount != null)
{
    acordSubAccount.OLifEExtension.Add(ACORDUtil.CreateOLifEExtension(OlifeExtensions));
    return acordSubAccount;
}
```

Comment: this will behave very differently to the original code; it will either *always* return from this branch, or it will throw an exception - either because there were zero matches, or because there were multiple.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes. It depends on their requirements. If there should only ever be one or no matching elements, then allowing multiple matches allows errors.

Comment: I'm assuming the requirements are to continue to behave **like the code shown in the question**, i.e. the `foreach`; in which case, you want `FirstOrDefault`, not `Single`; changing to `Single` changes the behaviour

Comment: @MarcGravell Sure. You are assuming the code in the question adheres to the requirements. I am pointing out to the OP that Single is a thing that exists, and is better practice to use than FirstOrDefault, for situations where exactly one match is expected and there should not ever be multiple matches (if that's what the business rules dictate). Note "perhaps" in the answer.

Comment: one would assume that the rest of the method wouldn't exist if this were the case...

Comment: @MarcGravell. Right, I get you. We're arguing different things. I was missing SingleOrDefault, vs FirstOrDefault. Single will throw an exception which isn't intended.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing the return statement you mentioned is the one inside the for loop: you're saying that you want to run a loop which returns something unconditionally on every iteration, which is bizarre to say the least, since the loop will be interrupted at the first iteration, return the first *acordSubAccount*, and exit the method.
You might need to reconsider what you want to accomplish with that loop and whether you even need it.